# octal or hexadecimal number to decimal in C

Tags: c

Scan a number along with its base value. If a number starts with 0 it is octal nd if it starts with 0x it is hexadecimal. print the corresponding decimal value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a,b;
scanf("%x %d",&a,&b);
printf("%d",a);`
}
```

3 test cases shows error .please help me with this.

Comment: See the [documentation for scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).  Take a look at what the `i` conversion specifier does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scanf i flag:

> Matches an optionally signed integer; the next pointer
> must be a pointer to int.  The integer is read in base 16
> if it begins with 0x or 0X, in base 8 if it begins with 0,
> and in base 10 otherwise.  Only characters that correspond
> to the base are used.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a,b;
    scanf("%i %i",&a,&b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);`
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Got it!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int oc,hex;
    scanf("%i",&oc);
    scanf("%i",&hex);
    printf("\ndecimal:%d",oc);
    printf("\ndecimal:%d",hex);
    return 0;
}
```

another way

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int oc,hex;
    printf("enter the octal value:");
    scanf("%o",&oc);
    printf("enter the hex value:");
    scanf("%x",&hex);
    printf("\noctal to decimal:%d",oc);
    printf("\nhex to decimal:%d",hex);
}
```